# How to get the name of selected files in source control via VSCode extension API?

Tags: visual-studio-code, version-control, vscode-extensions

I can manage to get one file name of source control with following code. The file name is from the line 'await vscode.commands.executeCommand('copyFilePath');' I can get the file name by reading the clipboard text. But when I select multiple files, still the first file name is available. Is it possible to get all files' name?

```
  let copySelectedFileName = vscode.commands.registerCommand('folder-operations.copySelectedFileName', async (folder) => {

    let newUri = folder;  // folder will be undefined when triggered by keybinding
    console.log('folder'+folder);
     if (!folder) {                       // so triggered by a keybinding
       await vscode.commands.executeCommand('copyFilePath');
     }
     console.log(newUri);
  });
```

I try another way: add one command to SCM as below shown.

[image]

I use parameter in command to retrieve the selected files' name. But the size of the array is 1 even if I choose more than 2 files.

```
let copySelectedFileNameSCM = vscode.commands.registerCommand('testSource.copySelectedFileNameSCM', async (...file) => {
        console.log('file:'+file);
      });
```

Comment: add more arguments to the command and see what they contain on multiple selection, or use `(...args)`

Comment: The arguments is empty. The file name is from the line 'await vscode.commands.executeCommand('copyFilePath');' I can get the file name by reading the clipboard text.

Comment: I was under the impression of getting the selected files in the explorer by adding a menu command

Comment: add a command to SCM: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/scm-provider#menus

Comment: Thanks for your advise rioV8. I am not very familiar about the SCM development and I am looking into the source-control-sample to know about how to do that. But I failed to execute the sample. Anyway, I will update here when I figure out something.

Comment: the SCM sample is way to complex because it shows how to implement your own SCM interface, like git, svn, rccs. Add a menu contribution point to the SCM view

Comment: I have added a command to SCM.  But I still can not get the files' name. I have updated the question.

Comment: you can file an issue, because this works in the explorer view, it should also work in the SCM view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your command to this context menu in your `package.json`:

```
    "contributes": {

        "menus": {

            "scm/resourceState/context": [
                {
                    "command": "testSource.copySelectedFileNameSCM"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

It looks like you were adding it to the wrong menu.  That may be the only menu that will return selected files.

Then in your command:

```js
let copySelectedFileNameSCM = vscode.commands.registerCommand('testSource.copySelectedFileNameSCM', async (...file) => {
   console.log('file:'+file);
});
```

`file` will be an array of all selected items in the scm view when you trigger a context menu **on one or more selected files**.